# User authentication in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails API which has several models, and controllers that return JSON. 
The API will be responsible for managing all the data, and there will be a 2nd app for serving the web front end.

I'm wondering where the users table and authentication controller should be.

The options would be:

- Keep authentication in the API, and build a web front end that queries for users/roles etc.
- Implement a Devise user in the front end, completely separate from the API.

Any idea's what the best practice is for this? 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What do you see the pros and cons of each being?

Comment: I think I need to do both. 
Implementing the Devise approach makes sense in the web front end - and that gives me a lot, like signup invites etc. 

And in the API - an authentication token that the front end uses(and any other API clients I might build in future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have

- 1 rails app with API
- 1 rails app that serves the front-end, and the 1st app actually serves as backend/database for this app

Correct?

In that case I would make sure

- use devise in the second (UI) app
- the authentication of the API is between two servers, and you could just use a simple/effective authentication-token
- the second server will protect the API from unauthorized access, since no client will ever see the url or authentication token (since it is server <-> server communication)

Comment: Thanks - this is the approach I went with in the end.